# Angular2 Assign Variable in div

Tags: angular, variables, block, assign

I have the following problem. How can I assign variable to variable in HTML block element (Angular 2)?

This is my code:

```
<div *ngIf="(_items && _items.length === 1) && !lookupModel" [lookupModal]="_items"> 
     {{lookUpModal}}
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show where exactly you want to assign a variable? what for?

Comment: "[lookupModal]="_items" here :D

Comment: This is not the syntax for variable assignment. What you wrote is called *property binding* in Angular. You should look it up in the docs.

Comment: So i did horrible mistake, then how Can i assign varriable _items to lookupModal? I want this operation in block element not in class :-/